# Button DataTemplate width too large

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, datatemplate, blend, visual-studio-2015

I created a DataTemplate from a Button and put the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` to `0`.  I set the width and height to 75 on the Grid of the DataTemplate.  The grid has a border and it's MinWidth and MinHeight are also both set to `0`.  The width and height of the border is set to auto(`75`).

Now when I put the button on my page it's width is `109.166664123535` and height is 75.  When viewing the DataTemplate in Blend it says the Grid and it's children are width of 75 but the DataTemplate itself wider.

How do I make the entire DataTemplate a `width` of `75` and not just the DataTemplate children?

**Edit 1**
After @Guttsy suggestions, this is what I changed the code to look like.  Also note NumberPadButtonStyle removes the top and bottom padding on the buttons ControlTemplate border.  The code is below:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="SetDominationsNumberPadButtonStyle"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}"
               TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="110" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="110" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Content="1" Style="{StaticResource SetDominationsNumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1"
            Content="2"
            Style="{StaticResource SetDominationsNumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="2"
            Content="3"
            Style="{StaticResource SetDominationsNumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Content="5"
            Style="{StaticResource SetDominationsNumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Content="6"
            Style="{StaticResource SetDominationsNumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Content="7"
            Style="{StaticResource SetDominationsNumberPadButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Button to be 75 units wide, then you should set Width on the Button itself to be 75. Do not force any particular width/height constraints in your ControlTemplate. You'll never be able to set Width/Height in your DataTemplate and have the ActualWidth/ActualHeight of your Button control match unless the Button has no chrome.

If you want your buttons to look consistently-sized, I'd recommend setting MinWidth (as opposed to Width) to a number that you would expect to work for most of your buttons. That way, should you decide to localize your application, you'll allow for longer translations to fit inside the buttons.

Note: I believe the styles for buttons and other controls on Windows Phone and Windows Store apps are, by default, optimized for touch, so the controls will be slightly larger than you expect them to be. I don't know if this is coming into play right now because your question is incomplete. Please include some XAML.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" x:Key="NumberPadButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="75" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        </Style>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>

    <Button Content="1" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="2" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="3" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="4" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="5" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="6" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="7" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="8" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
    <Button Content="9" Style="{StaticResource NumberPadButtonStyle}" />
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I'm making a number pad and thought setting the width and height to 75 on the DataTemplate would be the best approach so I only have to tweak it in one spot.

Comment: @Michael Well, you certainly don't want to have to specify it a dozen times. I've updated my answer with a potential solution.

Comment: It's telling me "UniformGrid is not supported in a Windows Phone project."  Also I have other style changes too.  For example grid background color change and border color change.

Comment: @Michael Serves me right for doing it in a WPF project instead of a Windows Phone one. You can just use a normal Grid instead and manually set the rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It appears it'll never go to 75 even if you hard code it outside the DataTemplate.  So it must be the ActualWidth preventing it from going below a certain threshold.